# Adding Complex Type Object to Object - Leaner Design Advice?

Tags: c#, oop, wcf-data-services, odata

I have a Project entity that is linked to an AffiliatedProject entity with a 0-to-* relationship, i.e. a Project can be affiliated with many other Projects.  I store these "related" Projects in the AffiliatedProject table where it basically looks like this:

```
Affiliated_Project
------------------
PK: Affiliated_Project_Id;
FK: Main_Project_Id
FK: Sub_Project_Id
```

I have a form that displays the main Project with a button that loads a subform where one can search for other projects to link to the main project.  This form searches against the Project collection.  Upon the user choosing a Project to link, I am creating a new AffiliatedProject object like so:

```
private void AddProject(Project proj)  // proj is the Project coming from the search form
{
   AffiliatedProject proj = new AffiliatedProject 
   {
      SubProject = new Project 
      {
        ProjId = proj.ProjId ,
        ProjName = proj.ProjName ,
        ProjectType = new ProjectType
        {
           Code = proj.ProjectType.Code
        }
      },
   MainProject = SelectedProject;
};
```

I tried just setting SubProject = proj, but that didn't seem to work.  Why is that?  Can someone please advise me on how I can better approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since you marked this as WCF DS question I assume the code above is from the WCF DS Client. Note that entities in WCF DS Client are not self tracking, so you have to notify the DataServiceContext of any changes you want to make. See this for more detail (especially the Creating and Modifying Relationship links): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756361.aspx

Comment: Actually, I am using WCF DS but the snippet above is not really related to WCF DS at that moment.  I probably could've used a better name for AddProject(), but basically I just want to get the newly received object of type <T> and assign it to another instance of another object of type <T>, i.e. the same type.

Comment: In that case, please post how is it "not working" and ideally some of the types (for example, what is the type of the SubProject property).